# Double Nav Bars when selecting "More..." items

Tags: ios6, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm using a storyboard in my iOS 6 app. At the root I have a Tab bar, then I have a number of view controller tabs, enough to get a "More..." item in the bar. Each tab view is embedded in a navigation controller, a very standard setup like the below, except there are more tabs than two, enough to show a "More..." item in the bar:

Yikes, as a newbie I can't post images. Here's a link to an image http://maybelost.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/sb22.jpg

The problem is, if you tap "More..." and then you tap one of the items in the overflow list, the view slides in but you get double Nav Bars.

At the top is the bar from the "More..." screen, which is blank except for the back button saying "More...". Just under that is the Navigation controller from the item I picked from the overflow screen, with its title and so on.

The app works normally but obviously this is bad. How can I prevent this?